# Changing the RDS password of an ElasticBeanstalk stack and reflecting that change in the application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

My ElasticBeanstalk stack includes an RDS instance, with the application using the `RDS_*` environment variables to connect.

I need to reset the RDS password, which is easy enough to do, but does anyone know if the EC2 servers will require restarting or similar in order to inherit the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EB does have to update the ec2 instances, but I don't think it's a full restart. I'm guessing you're wondering how long it will take; out of curiosity I just did a quick test in our dev environment, here is the event log:

```
2018-03-14 09:22:30 UTC-0700    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
2018-03-14 09:22:30 UTC-0700    INFO    Successfully deployed new configuration to environment.
2018-03-14 09:21:28 UTC-0700    INFO    Updating environment webtier's configuration settings.
2018-03-14 09:21:15 UTC-0700    INFO    Environment update is starting.
```

Looks like a little over a minute in total.

Comment: Did you have to do anything to prompt the update, or did EB notice the password change and trigger it itself?

Comment: @user1381745 EB noticed it on its own and handled everything. (I changed the value in the AWS console, not via command line)

Comment: @KayakinKoder do you mean that once password is updated in secret manager the EB application will refresh the servers to use new password and we don't need to anything? Also does it work when EB is using multiple ec2 instances with load balancer?

Comment: @lone_worrior this was for envrionment variables in the EB environment.  No I do not think if you update something in secret manater, EB will automatically roll out any changes

Comment: Yeah that was my understanding too. Thanks @KayakinKoder

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore?  I changed password via the aws console and if I `sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` after doing a new deployment it still has the old password.