# In an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, how can you change the database master password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

This was asked a few years ago ([Changing the RDS password of an ElasticBeanstalk stack and reflecting that change in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278243/changing-the-rds-password-of-an-elasticbeanstalk-stack-and-reflecting-that-chang)) but never fully answered and the systems seemed to have been changed.

If you have an EB environment with an RDS database (using Postgres in my case), it seems there is no way to change the master password on the database.

Now, you *can* change it, by opening the instance in the RDS console and typing in a new password. But that change won't propagate to the rest of the EB environment, from what I can tell. The environment variables (like RDS_PASSWORD) that use to access your database won't update.

Anyone know of a workaround for this?

I know that the environment variables are set in a file on the EC2 instance called

/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env

But, I can't figure out how how to change or override the contents of that file, and thus the environment variables that the instance sees when it is running. Directly editing it seems really dodgy.

One thing that does *not* work is going into the EB console and adding environment variable there - the contents of the env file mentioned above seems to take precedence.

Comment: You have to do it "manually" by overwriting all those variables.

Comment: But how do I do that? How do I overwrite the environment variables stored in the env file?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to figure this out for myself as well. For all the automatic stuff that happens when configuring things in AWS, this is a strangely manual outlier (but I'm really new to this, so maybe this is just how it is)

1. Elastic Beanstalk -> choose an environment -> Configuration -> Networking and Database, click edit
2. Scroll down to Database settings, there's a Password field there. Update the password and Apply

Verified that `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` had the right value after the instance updated.